# Prevent VSCode terminal from performing a post request in Angular

Tags: angular, post

I recently started learning Angular 16. I am trying to build a web using VSCode, running it locally with ng serve and checking in my Chrome browser.

At one point I perform a post call:

> let api_url = "https://login.eveonline.com/v2/oauth/token";
>
> const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Basic XXX',
> 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' };
>
> const body = "grant_type=authorization_code&code="+auth_code;
>
> console.log("Code: "  + auth_code);
>
> this.http.post(api_url, body, { headers: headers }).subscribe(data => {
> console.log("Data subscribed");
> console.log(data);
> });
> }

This goes neatly, the call is performed. But the answer is received in the Visual Studio Console. Since I can only use the key once, I get an error in Chrome.

If I comment this function I have checked that I get a successfull reply if I do the post call using curl in a terminal.

Is there a way to solve this issue? To make the console not run code so the web can get the reply while developing?